# Separating Words in a TextBox Into an Array

Tags: php

In PHP, how would one take a string and separate the words into an array? Is there a way to split them by the spaces in the string? Also, how would you check if a word in an array starts with a character? The idea would be to have a textbox with come normal words and a hashtag. The PHP script would maybe underline or change the color of the hashtag when you submit the form. It would basically underline any word that started with a hash. Sorry if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: example of the input in the question please.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to an array, use PHP's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
```

To examine whether each word begins with a certain character, you can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in a loop:

```
// Pick a letter
$char = 'a';
foreach ($array as $word) {
   if (strpos($word, $char) === 0) { 
      // Echo out what you want
      echo "$word contains $char\r\n"; 
      // Halt loop if necessary:
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about the starts with type thing?

Comment: how would I print out the array? I tried `echo` and `print_r` but it just printed "Array".

Comment: Do you want to print out each element of the array?